# Stellar Scam help

Tags: transactions

Hi hello I just lost $36k because I'm a gigantic idiot and didnt pay attention and fell for the staking scam. I assume that there is no fixing this?

https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/tx/8fdc844cd57c8749c35dd63f31ed963ae26ffc3b812cac321f6c7d48c404f08a